# Wrong picture/thumbnail when we paste the link to our post from our blog

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph, image

We run the blog Tracasseur http://www.tracasseur.com and been doing it for 4 years. We have the blog at Blogger. Always when we post the link to our latest post on our Facebook page https://www.facebook.com/tracasseur the right picture from the post has been chosen. But suddenly the other day it has stopped working. Now Facebook only give us the opportunity to choose between 2 pictures that are not included in the post, but they are on the blog in the right column. How can we solve this problem? And why has this problem suddenly occurred, we haven't changed anything?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the image to use in your blog's HTML meta tags, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Edit: Looks like your blog is handled by blogger, there are more specific instructions for that here: http://www.bloggerhow.com/2012/07/implement-open-graph-in-blogger-blogs.html

Comment: But does it have to be this complicated? We just want the right picture that are in the post to show up. For example the picture in top of this post: http://www.tracasseur.com/2013/02/moon-boots-no-one.html
Must we really go in and add og:tags to fix this problem? And must we add all of them or just a few? And we just want to make it once, so Facebook understands that it should fetch the picture included in the post. So we don't have to change codes whenveer we should share a link on our Facebook-page.

Comment: I should point out [this tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tracasseur.com%2F2013%2F02%2Fmoon-boots-no-one.html) too, which lets you debug your URLs to see exactly what Facebook sees for any URL you want. You can see that since no `og:image` tag is provided, Facebook is inferring the image to use.

Comment: Ok, so I have to add og:image code intot our code. What should we out in and where in the code? I tried to put this code in:

<meta property="og:title" content="tracasseur" />
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.tracasseur.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.tracasseur.com" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="http://www.tracasseur.com" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="616023012" />

Comment: Follow the tutorial in the second link I posted. It gives you some code you can just paste in and should work without much modification.